# Flutter Error: The current Flutter SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.0.0.flutter-be6309690f

Tags: dart, flutter

I've just upgraded my flutter, after upgradation I am unable to run any flutter project on my Android Studio. I am getting this error message.

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.0.0.flutter-be6309690f.

Because buddy depends on flutter_built_redux 0.4.5 which requires SDK 
version >=1.19.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.                                                  
pub get failed (1)
```

How can I downgrade Dart or how can I resolve this issue, I am running android studio on mac.

I've tried by changing flutter channels `dev` and `master` but it doesn't make a difference.

flutter doctor -v result:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v0.6.0, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E202, locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 0.6.0 at /Users/pro/Downloads/flutter
• Framework revision 9299c02cf7 (5 days ago), 2018-08-16 00:35:12 +0200
• Engine revision e3687f70c7
• Dart version 2.1.0-dev.0.0.flutter-be6309690f

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
  • Android SDK at /Users/pro/Library/Android/sdk
  • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native 
     profiling support)
  • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
  • Java binary at: /Applications/Android 
     Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
  • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release- 
     1024-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 9.4.1, Build version 9F2000
• ios-deploy 1.9.2
• CocoaPods version 1.5.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin version 27.1.1
• Dart plugin version 173.4700
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[!] Connected devices
! No devices available
```

Comment: Have you tried switching between Dart@1 and Dart@2 ? Run `brew info dart`

Comment: How can I switch between Dart@1 and Dart@2 ?

Comment: You can use this to switch `brew switch dart version_id`

Comment: Yes, I did that but I think I need to have multiple dart sdk installed for this.

Comment: Ok, you installed the most recent version, so you're looking to downgrade it ?

Comment: Yes, I've changed the dart sdk version by using this command `brew switch dart version_id`, its changed but when I run flutter doctor -v, there is still dart version is `• Dart version 2.1.0-dev.0.0.flutter-be6309690f`

Comment: try to upgrade flutter_built_redux, Latest one is flutter_built_redux: ^0.5.0

Comment: You can still install an older version `brew install dart`. If you don't add --devel option, it will install the stable one.

Comment: I've installed but its again not gonna make any difference in error.

Comment: Get rid of flutter_built_redux and packages which depend on it, or update it to the latest version

Comment: `flutter_built_redux` is available in version `0.6.0` which is compatible with latest Flutter. You probably had a version constraint in `pubspec.yaml` that prevent this latest version to be chosen.

Answer (score 6):

`flutter_built_redux` package doesn't met the flutter dependency.
The error is caused by package not by flutter sdk.

see here
https://github.com/davidmarne/flutter_built_redux/blob/master/pubspec.yaml#L22

AND

you can post issue on `flutter_built_redux` package using this link
https://github.com/davidmarne/flutter_built_redux/issues/new?title=support%20for%20flutter%20sdk%202.1.0.dev&body=please%20upgrade%20the%20package%20for%20new%20flutter%20releases

Comment: I've used fresh installation of android studio and configured flutter and dart plugin again, then this is working fine for me. and `flutter_built_redux ` is also working properly now.

Answer (score 4):

Flutter includes a bundled Dart SDK (under its `bin/cache` directory) pinned to the same version used in the engine that we compile into your shipping iOS/Android app. As such, the only way to use Flutter with a different version of Dart is to use an older version of Flutter.

To do this, `cd` to the Flutter SDK directory. You can list the available versions by running `git tag`. To switch to a version, use `git checkout`. For example, to switch to `v0.8.1` you’d run `git checkout v0.8.1`. When you’d like to switch back to the beta channel, run `git checkout beta`.

That said, generally I’d advise you to stick to `beta` and file an issue (or send a pull request) to the maintainer of any packages that haven’t yet been updated to Dart 2. You may also want to check the dependencies listed in your `pubspec.yaml` to see if there are newer versions available on [pub.dartlang.org](https://pub.dartlang.org). It may just be a matter of updating your dependencies to a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is an quiver package dependency problem. Once in an update i had face same issue. That time i solve this by adding this lines to `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependency_overrides:
  quiver: ^2.0.0+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has the following channels, in increasing order of stability:

**master**

**dev**

**beta**

**stable**

Generally, I’d advise you to stick to the beta it works fine with all the packages.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary but i think you should have to install Android Studio again with latest version.then add flutter and dart plugin there then Add Flutter SDK path in settings>Plugins>Flutter>Sdk-Path so locate your flutter sdk that you have installed in your PC may be located at C so add that path.And it may work.

And must have latest Flutter and Dart SDK installed.
You can download flutter SDK from here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases